# Can If Condition activity selectively execute 1 or more multiple activities after it?

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]

Using the simple pipeline layout above, I want to be able to selectively run any or all of the activities to the right of the If Condition activity based on a parameter value. Or is this an "all or nothing" execution?

Like if the parameter is 3 then run the stored procedure and function but not the other two or if the parameter is 5 then run all but the function or if the parameter is 8 then only run the function and so on to however many scenarios required.

Thus far, the only way I am able to make this work is to give each activity on the right its own If Condition activity and put a Fail activity inside the "False" activity for each of those If Condition activities where the parameter doesn't check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use switch activity wherein you can use a single expression based on multiple if expressions for your different use cases
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity

Comment: Thank you for this. I will give this a try and follow-back.